# Docker - How do I mount my database local to database of container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm a new guy to learn about docker. 
I'm working on my computer, just me. do some basic code and connect to local database, use workbench to show tables and do query on that. ok, Then there is some guy come to my project. That guy does front-end, but he also need my back-end(my code) to test. basically, I can give that guy my project and install some stuff to let my code work on that guy's computer. But i don't want do that, i want to use docker-compose. ok that's context

So i'm connecting to db local, but now switch to use container. How do i reuse the local db(ex: dating_db) in that container, how that container connect to my local db,

I have tried to change **./mysql** to **C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Data**
but it didn't work

Do i am wrong or missed something, pls explain for me, thank you!

```
services:
    dating_app_db:
        image: mysql:8.0.19
        command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
        ports: 
            - '3306:3306'
        volumes:
            - "./mysql:/var/lib/mysql"
        restart: always
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: $MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
            MYSQL_DATABASE: $MYSQL_DATABASE
            MYSQL_USER: $MYSQL_USER
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: $MYSQL_PASSWORD
    api:
        build:
          context: .
          dockerfile: Dockerfile
        command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
        container_name: api_service
        volumes:
          - .:/api_service
        ports:
          - "8000:8000"
        env_file: .env
        links: 
          - dating_app_db
        depends_on: 
          - dating_app_db
        restart: always
```

I just use docker-compose up to start

Comment: Are you running two databases, one on your host and one in Docker?  Can you include any relevant source code or configuration in your question (as text, not in an image, and directly in the question)?  Can you give a specific example of a command or request you're running that's giving unexpected results?

Comment: What do you mean with this: "how to mount the database of container to local's database"? Do you need to start a new db container pre-populated with your local database?

Comment: @DavidMaze, No i just want to run one database, i just want to run container and it can bind to my local. I've edited that post, thank you

Comment: @JRichardsz, I mean, i have a mysql local and I use IDE such as workbench to work. then i run a container database, I want that container bind to mysql local, it will convenient for me to see and test. and also use the database has existed in my local

Comment: What is your real goal or question? An experiment to create a container based on your localhost db o share your source code?  What do you mean with this "and I don't want give that source for another one, because they have to install and setup many things.".  So you have your work in your laptop(api+db) and do you need to share it to some coworker?

Comment: @JRichardsz, Okey, imagine that, I'm working on my computer, just me. do some basic code and connect to local database, use workbench to show tables and do query on that. ok, Then there is some guy come to my project. That guy does front-end, but he also need my back-end(my code) to test. basically, I can give that guy my project and install some stuff to let my code work on that guy's computer. But i don't want do that, i want to use docker-compose. ok that's context

So i'm connecting to db local, but now switch to use container. How do i reuse the local db(ex: dating_db) in that container

Comment: If you would be in a software company, you must upload your api source code to some git repository. This repository must have everything necessary for any of the team to start it, in your case docker. The same goes for the database. **NOBODY** share its internal database organs. Just share your database as script. You can use docker `volumes: - ./database:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`

Another approach is to have an environment(aws , gcp, azure, heroku, openshift, digitalocean, etc) in which you must deploy the api to be used for any guy in your team.

Comment: @JRichardsz I decided to host a database on server for easy to test, thank you for suggestion